# How to restore mysql databases from file disk

Tags: mysql, restore, database, database-administration

I used to have a few mysql databases on my system, but my operating system crashed and I cannot access the installed mysql service anymore. The only thing that I have is access to the database files in `/var/lib/mysql`. I searched in forums about the ways to retrieve the databases, but I didn't get the right answer (My engine is InnoDB).

The things that I did:

1. I stoped the mysqld service
2. copied the contents of `/var/lib/mysql/` into a new installed operating system,
3. changed the permissions and owner
4. started the mysqld service

now I have access to databases, but not table rows.

- `show databases` it returns the names of all the databases,
- `use database dbname` it connects to a database,
- `show tables` it returns the names of the tables in that database
- `select * from atable` returns error: `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table
  'dbname.atable' doesn't exist`

Is there a strightforward way to return the databases?

Comment: were you using MyIsam or InnoDB tables?

Comment: @golimar it was InnoDB.

Comment: take a look at table information_schema.tables to see if everything there makes sense

Comment: My old tables are not listed there

Comment: You said SHOW TABLES returns the tables in that database, that includes your old tables?

Comment: yes, it includes those tables but not their rows.

Comment: change to user mysql with 'su' and try to read the files in /var/lib/mysql , including the ibdata and ib_logfile ones (for example using the 'file' command on them)

Comment: It has access to those files. I mean I opened them and even edited them.

Comment: I just copied the folder on my friends computer and it worked perfectly!